# How to add image to multipart via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing the dropzone.js file upload. However I do not want dropzone to handle the uploads because it seems like they go in bursts instead of all at once. I would like my photos to be uploaded at one time. To do so users will drag and drop photos into the dropzone area. From here they choose some custom options on the images. Then I would like a user to hit a custom button. This button can perform the following.

1. Add photos to multiImg[] array
2. invoke form

After a photo is uplaoded into the dropzone I will have access to all the information about the photo. Name, size, location(on uers computer). I am just unsure how to accomplish step 1 which is to take the photos and pass them into a form via javascript.

Is this even a good approach?

```
 <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" accept='image/*' name="multiImg[]" id="multiImg" />
```

Or possibly programatically appending

```
<input type="file" accept='image/*' name="Img" id="Img" />
```

Tags to the form and then submitting the form when done would be acceptable as well.

Can you dynamically add to the FileList for an input?

Comment: Have a look at the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object - that should give you some ideas about how to deal with #1 :-)

Comment: added form, for some reason it wasnt showing.

Answer (score 0):

This got me closer to a solution.

```
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    formData = new FormData();

 formData.append("" + paramNm + (this.uploadMult ? "[]" : ""), file, fileName);
xhr.send(formData);
```